# Kibana, why time range doesn't end at now?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

For example, I'd like to see # of events for 28 days(month) for 28 * 3 days period..

TSVB graph doesn't start at the `28*3 days past` nor ends at `now` as shown in the pick.

The graph ends at 2019-12-26 which is 23 days ago from today..

[image]

Comment: IMO you're hitting some weird bug — I've opened https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/55284

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect it to be a bug, I thought I must be doing something wrong..

Comment: It definitely looks weird to me, so we'll see